# Get total count of meta_values from a query of posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to return a total count of a meta value from each post in a query of posts.

So, for example, I query to get posts with the args of a custom post type, and the author being the current author. That part is easy - to return the actual posts and also to count the posts. But I want to count a meta value from each of the posts in the query and return a total count. The meta value is a count of how many times the post has been Favorited. The meta key is 'simplefavorites_count' and I'm using this plugin here for reference:

https://favoriteposts.com/

To give some more information, this is for use on a custom user dashboard page which will show a user how many times their posts of any post type have been Favorited by other users. So for example, 'Your Fan Art posts have been Favorited 67 times in total'.

This is what I tried so far:

```
<?php

$theposts = get_posts(array(
        'post_type' => 'fan_art',
        'author'    => $current_user->ID,
        'numberposts' => -1,
)); 

$countFavs = 0;

foreach($theposts as $p):

$pCount = get_post_meta($p->ID, 'simplefavorites_count', true);

$countFavs += count($pCount);

endforeach;

echo $countFavs;

?>
```

Anyone have any ideas how I can get this count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code.

```
$theposts = get_posts( array(
    'post_type'   => 'fan_art',
    'author'      => $current_user->ID,
    'numberposts' => -1,
) ); 

$countFavs = 0;

foreach( $theposts as $p ):

    $pCount = get_post_meta( $p->ID, 'simplefavorites_count', true );

    echo $p->post_title .' View is - '. $pCount."</br>";

    $countFavs = $countFavs + $pCount;

endforeach;

echo 'All posts total view is - '. $countFavs."</br>";
```

Comment: Why can't you just use the PHP count function with get post meta